# Databinding via Interface

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I have a simple databinding setup:

My ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel {

    public ObservableField<Integer> viewVisibility = new ObservableField<>(View.VISIBLE);

    public void buttonClicked() {
        if (viewVisibility.get() == View.GONE) {
            viewVisibility.set(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            viewVisibility.set(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

and the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.fweigl.playground.MyViewModel" />

    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="64dp">

        <View
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.viewVisibility}"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="#00ff00" />

        <Button
            android:text="click me"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.buttonClicked()}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

As you can see, every click on the button switches the `ObservableField<Integer> viewVisibility` on the viewmodel, which in turn switches the visibility of a green rectangle. **This works fine.**

**Now I want to do the same but using an interface as a viewmodel:**

```
public interface IMyViewModel {

    public void buttonClicked();

    public ObservableField<Integer> viewVisibility = new ObservableField<>(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

the viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel implements IMyViewModel {
    @Override
    public void buttonClicked() {
        if (viewVisibility.get() == View.GONE) {
            viewVisibility.set(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            viewVisibility.set(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

and in the layout, I import the interface instead of the implementation:

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.fweigl.playground.IMyViewModel" />

</data>
```

What works is the binding for the button click, `buttonClicked` is called and the value of `viewVisibility` is changed.

**What doesn't work** is the changing of the green rectangle view's visibility. Changes of the `viewVisibility` value are not reflected in the layout.

Am I doing something wrong or does databinding not (fully) work with interfaces as viewmodels?

Answer (score 0):

Id you'd wrap whatever variable you'd like to bind to your view in a LiveData<>, Android will automatically unbox the data and bind it to the view

Answer (score 0):

Data binding needs getter and setter to make work done, it does not access your field directly. So this will also not work without getter setter

```
public class MyViewModel {

    public ObservableField<Integer> viewVisibility = new ObservableField<>(View.VISIBLE);

    public void buttonClicked() {
        if (viewVisibility.get() == View.GONE) {
            viewVisibility.set(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            viewVisibility.set(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

So because interface does not have getter setter, so they can not be used as model.

Comment: By the way why you are putting this variable in ViewModel whether it should be placed in Model class? ViewModel are used to hold related data like Model, or listeners.

Comment: Databinding definitely does not need a getter to access an ObservableField as long as it's public. Else my first ViewModel wouldn't work either, but it does.